# String value from constructor to Apex methods

Tags: apex, visualforce, constructor

I have set a value to a static string variable in constructor and while I try to access that value in my apex methods , I always receives as NULL.

```
public class Mycontroller {
    public static string fieldvalue {get;set;}
    //Constructor
    public Mycontroller (){
        String param1 = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('param1');
                After some calculations set the value in fieldvalue

                fieldvalue = '123456';
            }

           The function updaterecordreq is getting called from an actionfunction in VF page:

           <button type="button" onclick="updateuser();">Click Me</button>
           <apex:actionFunction name="updateuser" action="{!updaterecordreq}" reRender="none" />

    public void updaterecordreq(){
        system.debug('Event clicked'+fieldvalue);
    }
}
```

Once updaterecordreq is called from the action function , I see that in updaterecordreq method, the value is null though I set the same in the constructor.

How do i set something in constructor and referenced the same in other apex methods in the same transaction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Static variables (as well as those marked `transient`) are not persisted through the view state, so you have to remove the static keyword to make it a member variable.  If you need it to be static for some other reason, you could create another member variable of the same type and populate it before doing anything else:

```
public class Mycontroller {
    public static string fieldvalue {get;set;}
    public string fieldvaluemember {get;
               set{myController.fieldvalue = value; fieldvaluemember = value;}
    }
    //Constructor
    public Mycontroller (){
        String param1 = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('param1');

        fieldvaluemember = '123456';
    }

    public void updaterecordreq(){
        fieldvalue = fieldvaluemember;
        system.debug('Event clicked'+fieldvalue);
    }
}
```

Comment: One small question - It means if I use any member variable with being marked as static , the value that is set in constructor can be accessed across all apex methods of that apex class ? is that correct?

Comment: @Quddus Static doesn't change the access level of a variable, that's for the access level modifiers like `public`.  A Static variable just means that it is not tied to specific __instance__ of a class, so there is effectively "one copy" of the variable, no matter how many objects of the class' type you instantiate.  In the context of a page controller, however, you will usually use page controller classes as singletons, which means there will only ever be one instance of it when your page is running anyway, so the difference is just how you reference the variable in another class.

Comment: If you need more information about static v member variables, you should read the documentation at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_static.htm#!